# Generic constraint on multiple type variables

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I write types for existing library. I've faced with problem of defining constraint for type where two variable types should satisfy some limitation (T1[T2] should be an array of some type).

I have 1st interface

```
interface GenericInterfaceWithArray<ElementType> {
  arrayOfElements: ElementType[];
  push: (value: ElementType) => void;
}
```

and second one which uses previous one and also has 2 type variables:

```
interface OuterInterface<
  ObjectContainingArray,
  KeyOfPropertyWithArray extends keyof ObjectContainingArray
> {
  nestedProperty: GenericInterfaceWithArray<ObjectContainingArray[KeyOfPropertyWithArray]>;
  // line above has incorrect definition because
  // ObjectContainingArray[KeyOfPropertyWithArray] is an array
  // - can I take type from 'first array element' here?
  // smth like this line below

  // GenericInterfaceWithArray<ObjectContainingArray[KeyOfPropertyWithArray][0]>;
  // this does not work:
  // `Type '0' cannot be used to index type 'ObjectContainingArray[KeyOfPropertyWithArray]'.`
}
```

Usage:

```
interface InterfaceWithArrayProp {
  arrayProp: number[];
}

const myType: OuterInterface<InterfaceWithArrayProp, 'arrayProp'>;
myType.nestedProperty.push(25); // here should be validation for `number`.
// Currently I have type: `number[]`
```

I've tried defining inner interface in alternative way: as generic of array (less satisfying but acceptable if there is no way for first version):

```
interface GenericInterfaceWithArray<ArrayOfElements extends Array<any>> {
  arrayOfElements: ArrayOfElements;
  push: (value: ArrayOfElements[0]) => void;
}
```

But now I have an error from `OuterInterface`: `Type 'ObjectContainingArray[KeyOfPropertyWithArray]' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'.`

Is it possible to define that `T1[T2]` is an array and pass type of this first element as parameter for another generic interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out that I can use conditional types.

```
type FirstArrayElement<ElementsArrayType> = ElementsArrayType extends any[] ? ElementsArrayType[0] : never;

interface OuterInterface<
  ObjectContainingArray,
  KeyOfPropertyWithArray extends keyof ObjectContainingArray
> {
  nestedProperty: GenericInterfaceWithArray<FirstArrayElement<ObjectContainingArray[KeyOfPropertyWithArray]>>;
}
```